# Forbidden 403 Error in spring boot when i try to access the web app (index.html) or reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have my spring boot application and I have added the index.html file in the `'src/main/resources/static'`  folder under the spring boot application so that i can access the web page while running the spring boot server. This works perfectly in another spring boot application without spring web security setup. But once I add the spring web security configuration, I only get 403 Forbidden errors.  Online I found I should add: ".csrf().disable()" to my configure but it didn't work. I am trying to access the `localhost:8080` but all in vain. Spring security is needed to protect the REST API from unauthenticated users. This is my spring security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecuritySettings extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // enable cors and disable csrf tokens(only required in mvc not in rest)
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // disable session management immediately since we are using jwt tokens.
        // the server doesn't need to persist the currently logged-in user
        http = http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and();
        // configure your authorisation from here
        http.authorizeRequests()
               //.antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // for the default landing page
                .antMatchers("/api/accounts/create-user").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/accounts/me").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/payments").hasAuthority("client")
```

I also tried to render the page via the controller as suggested by others but all that in vain.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String renderLandingPage(){
        return "Welcome to the servspace";
    }

}
```

THis is error that I get
[image: 403 Forbidden error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need the `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` but it needs to be at the end because it is the most general:

```
   http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/accounts/create-user").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/accounts/me").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/payments").hasAuthority("client")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // for the default landing page
```

Comment: Yes it resolved the issue. Thanks. Also there is no need to define the request mapping in the `IndexController` as it would lead to another 403 template parsing error.                         rg.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing